# AFNetworking send image as file not as data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, afnetworking, nsdata

Hi server that I'm sending data is expecting image as file(jpg) not as NSData. This code works, but server can't recognize NSData as image. Any thoughts how to solve this?

```
+ (void)signupWithParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
            andUserHaveImage:(BOOL)userHaveImage
                    andImage:(NSData *)image
                successBlock:(void (^) (NSDictionary *response))successHandler
                  errorBlock:(void (^) (NSDictionary *error))errorHandler
{
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"multipart/form­data" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    [manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/api/1.0/customer/sign-up", DEFAULT_URL] parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {
        if (userHaveImage == YES) {
//  

      [formData appendPartWithFileData:image name:@"img_profile" fileName:@"profileImage.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
        [formData appendPartWithFormData:image name:@"img_profile"];
    }

} progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    successHandler(responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    errorHandler(@{});
}];
```

}

Comment: Stefan Are you converting the image to data by UIImageJPEGRepresentation or UIImagePNGRepresentation?

Comment: NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profileImageView.image, 1);
Yes, that server guy told me he sees that data, but he's expecting file(image.jpg)

Comment: meme type, try this @"image/jpeg"

Comment: Also tried that, same problem... Thanks for suggestion...

Comment: [formData appendPartWithFormData:image name:@"img_profile"]; this should not there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by converting image to UTF8 string and sending it in that format.